# How can I access a resource inside a VPC from a resource outside the VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, platform

Working on a serverless infrastructure and wish to send a request to a lambda outside a VPC from a lambda inside a VPC.

What is the best way to do this? Any AWS services that make this easy?

Comment: Does the VPC have an Internet Gateway?

Comment: More important: does it have a NAT? If yes, then requests should be transparent. If not, then you'll need to either create one (and pay to keep it running) or create a VPC Endpoint for Lambda (and pay to keep it running).

Comment: The question title and question text are opposite.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass the function ARN of your lambda in target VPC and use it to invoke it from another with something like this :

```
    const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({
        region: 'eu-east-1,
        apiVersion: '2015-03-31',
        
    }); 

      const params: InvocationRequest = {
        FunctionName: 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-east-1:999999999999:function:my-custom-function,
        InvocationType: 'RequestResponse',
        LogType: 'None',
        Payload: JSON.stringify(someRequest),
    };
    const response = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
```

Comment: This won't work if there's no route from the VPC private subnet (where the Lambda is running) to the Internet.